# ERB disable a button after certain amount of answers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

So I am making an Q&A website in Rails as a pet project and want to disable the button to post more answers after a certain amount. But currently with my solution I get this error

**Showing /vagrant/RailsBoard/app/views/questions/show.html.erb where line #20 raised:
compared with non class/module**

so I think there's something wrong in my embedded Ruby

```
<div class="container">
  <% if @answers > 3 %>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-  target="#answermodal">Submit new answer</button>
  </div>
  <% else %>
  bump
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I stand corrected. if @answers.count > 3 should work. I'm seriously surprised at that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `@answers` is a number.

You probably initialized it in your controller as a collection (`Array` or `ActiveRecord::Relation`); something along the lines of

```
@answers = Answer.where(question_id: params[:question_id])
```

Using `if @answers.size > 3` should work.